# How to update podman's storage limit?

Tags: centos, podman

I want to limit the disk space occupied by my podman container. Since the container has already been created and has undergone many configurations inside, it is difficult for me to create a new container to complete the disk quota.

I tried this command finish my task:

```
# podman update --storage-opt size=512M lms
```

It failed, and print this message on the screen:

```
Error: storage options overlay.size and overlay.inodes not supported. Filesystem does not support Project Quota: failed to set quota limit for projid 3391720445 on /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/backingFsBlockDev: function not implemented
```

I tried to find answer with ChatGPT and Bing Copilot, but it seems that I failed.

How can I update the storage limit?

Comment: I am using podman version 4.8.1

Comment: How did you apply a disk quota in the first place?